# Dynamic font size in css with calc

Tags: css, math

Good morning guys, I want to change the font size in my menu via calc in css but I don't know how this formula should look like.

At `@media screen and (max-width: 800 px)` is the beginning with 2 em at 600 px the font size should've 1.5 em and at 400 px 1 em. Does someone know how to do it?

I want also all the steps between those pixel widths. Like 765 px = x em

Thats my code so far:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#menu a{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    font-size:2em;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #menu a{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    font-size:1.5em;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #menu a{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    font-size:1em;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
}
```

But I want to compress the code that I've only one media query

Comment: That's a **lot** of media queries you're talking about, would responsive font sizes be a better solution for you? Also, can you share your current code?

Comment: Thats the point! I want only one media querie therefore shall be the formula.

Ok, I'll ad my code in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### An introduction to responsive font-sizes

Responsive font sizes can be enabled by using [viewport relative units.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
By combining a base size (1em) and a viewport related unit (vmin, or viewport-minimum of the smallest side).

```css
#small {
 font-size: calc(1em + 1vmin);
}

#medium {
 font-size: calc(1em + 2vmin);
}

#large {
 font-size: calc(1em + 3vmin);
}
```

```html
<div id="small">Small text</div>
<div id="medium">Medium text</div>
<div id="large">Large text</div>
```

Combining these with media queries can enhance the size since you can apply a larger default to these sections, for example: a large screen media query can look like this:

```css
#small {
 font-size: calc(1em + 1vmin);
}

#medium {
 font-size: calc(1em + 2vmin);
}

#large {
 font-size: calc(1em + 3vmin);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    #small {
     font-size: calc(1.3em + 1vmin);
    }
    
    #medium {
     font-size: calc(1.3em + 2vmin);
    }
    
    #large {
     font-size: calc(1.3em + 3vmin);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="small">Small text</div>
<div id="medium">Medium text</div>
<div id="large">Large text</div>
```

Notice the sudden increase when your screen size becomes larger than `700px`? You can use this method to pinpoint sizes while maintaining a responsive layout for your fonts.

In addition to this, CSS-Tricks has an [excellent article](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) on the usage of these.